# Covering Torus by torus

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

This question concerns example 1.41 in Hatcher's Algebraic topology. There he constructs a covering for the genus 3 surface by the genus 11 surface by shaping it like a star with 5 arms with two holes in each arm and one at the center. Then he quotients the 11 genus surface by $\mathbb{Z}_5$ to get the genus 3 surface (I am sorry I dont know how to include pictures. Now because this cover space is normal, the group of deck transformations, that is $\mathbb{Z}_5$, is isomorphic to the fundamental group of the surface of genus 3 over the subgroup the induced by the image of the cover space. So that we conclude the fundamental group of the genus 11 surface is a subgroup of the fundamental group of the genus 3 surface and has index 5. Now my question is this.. If I replace the arms of the 11 holed surface by arms with no holes, I will get something homeomorphic to the torus. Doing exactly the same procedure as before, the cover space is still normal the deck transformations are again $\mathbb{Z}_5$, I am going to end up concluding that the fundamental group of the torus contains itself as a subgroup of index 5... but this seems weird, can someone please explain what I am not thinking right??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually that's correct. The fundamental group of the torus is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, and, for example, the subgroup generated by $(1,0) $ and $(0,5)$ is an index 5 subgroup. Indeed it is easy to come up with a covering map $p:T^2 \to T^2$ of arbitrary (finite) degree. As you mention, the group of deck transformations in this picture can be taken to be a cyclic group of rotations.

Comment: okay I see. thanks